# Stripe API: List all Charges

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am using https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#list_charges to get **List all Charges** but here they specify

> count optional —  default is 10 A limit on the number of objects to be
>   returned. Count can range between 1 and 100 items.

and I have thousands of entries, now how can I get all. Though if I set count to **100** it returns **110** records.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes I got it with **offset** we can get all records.
[image]

Comment: Looks like you ought to have accepted @Chirag's answer - he/she beat you to it by several days! Would you might ticking theirs? `:)`

Answer (score 20):

You can use the `offset` argument.

Once you get the 100 transactions, then make another call by adding `offset=100` in URL.

This will bring the next 100 transactions, then make `offset=200` and so on.

**Update:**
`offset` parameter is partly deprecated: [API changelog - 2015-09-23](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2015-09-23)

Answer (score 4):

```
$charges = \Stripe\Charge::all();
foreach ($charges->autoPagingIterator() as $charge) {
  // Do something with $charge
}
```

[Reference.](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#pagination)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a PHP example:  `\Stripe\Charge::all(array("limit" => 3, "offset" => 10));`

A Ruby example:
`Stripe::Charge.all(limit: 3, offset:3)`

As good as the Stripe API docs are, they could be clearer on how to filter.

source: https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#list_charges, https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#list_charges

Answer (score 0):

> in case offset is deprecated

```
  $result = [];
  $created_at = strtotime($request->end_data);
  //created_at should be today's date epoch. search google for epoch
  $has_more = false;
  $a = 0;
  do{
  print_r($a);
  \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
  $temp = \Stripe\BalanceTransaction::all( array(
                'limit'   => 100,
                'created' => array(
                    'lte' => $created_at,
                )
              ));
  $result = array_merge($temp->data,$result);
  $created_at = $temp->data[99]->created_at;
  //api returns a parameter has_more(boolean), which means there is more 
  //data or not so you can also put that in while condition, for ex.
  // $has_more = $temp->has_more;
  $a++;

  }while($a < 5);

  dd($result);
```

**this worked for me** i was able to get 500 records at once as $a < 5 the api hits 5 times and each time created parameter which is lte (less than equal) changes for each api request and return previous records than current request provide. also i am appending the result of each api call to another result array

Answer (score -5):

Unfortunately you can't.

I can see where such a feature would be nice for accounting purposes or whatever, but it's generally a better user experience to implement some sort of paging when displaying copious amounts of data to the user.

If you need absolute control over how many records to display at a time, I would suggest setting up a webhook on the charge.succeeded event and store your charges locally.